# PHP editing/update mysql table with Edit button

Tags: php, sql-update

Ive made this blog and I need a little help, this is the index.php where the posts are being printed, same with their images...

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
}else{

echo "<a href=\"edit.php?id=".$image."\"><strong>EDIT</strong>";
}
?>
```

and here is edit.php

```
 <?php
 $_GET['id']
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BlogData id");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql){
$title = $row['title'];
$content = $row['content'];
$category = $row['category'];
$image = $row['id'];
$extension= $row['ext'];

 ?>

 <center>
 <form action='edit.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Title: <input type='text' name='title' placeholder="$title" /><br>
    Date: <input type='text' name='category' placeholder="$category" /><br>
 <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='content'>$content</textarea><br>
    <?php 
echo "<img width='228' height='60' src='uploads/".$image.".".$extension."'>";
  ?>
Select image to upload:
     <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
 <br><br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="edit!" name="submit">
 </form>
 <img src="images/tutorialpost2.jpg">
 </center>

 ?>
```

So I've got this EDIT button and I want it to work. It should be able to edit all my MySQL table 
with the current ID. how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
  <button>
}
```

Comment: oh simple :D now what can I do about the editing part?

Comment: Do you mean the form to put in new values to be updated into the database? You might want to try a tutorial on that. The principal is pretty good explained by [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Comment: yeah i got the button working... how can I make an auto-increment for each id so it can edit all atributes on the table?

Comment: I need this "EDIT" button to edit my posts... like, if I misswrite something, so I can correct using the button. same thing as the edit button used on this website...